# How do I uninstall spree_frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a project that installed all the `spree` gems, but now it will function as an API/backend only. I want to **get rid of all the user routes** in the Spree app, I wouldn't have them if `spree_frontend` wasn't installed in the first place.

I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
rake spree_frontend:remove
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your `Gemfile` to include only the `spree_` gems you need. so instead of:

```
gem 'spree'
```

list out the individual gems (remove `spree_frontend` specifically and re-bundle)

```
gem 'spree_api'
gem 'spree_backend'
gem 'spree_core'
# gem 'spree_frontend'
```